# Emacs dynamically change font-size based on window width and fill-column

Tags: emacs, fonts, size

I'm using Emacs on a small netbook to write code, and I've set the font size so that approximately fill-column(79) characters fill the width of a single 'maximized' window (ie pretty big font size). However, if I open two windows side by side, I would like the font size in those windows to automatically shrink so that each window's width accommodates at least 79 characters.

Before I start looking deep into this (I'm not good at Lisp), is it possible to get the window's width on each resize, divide it by fill-columns, and based on that result select a monospaced font size?

Comment: It should be possible, although your font preference has some role to play in determining height of the font after each split and unsplit. look at these functions `frame-pixel-width` `frame-char-width` `set-face-attribute`

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the right place to do this would be `window-size-change-functions`:

> Functions called before redisplay, if window sizes have
>   changed. The value should be a list of functions that take one
>   argument. Just before redisplay, for each frame, if any of its windows
>   have changed size since the last redisplay, or have been split or
>   deleted, all the functions in the list are called, with the frame as
>   argument.

Specifically, stick something like this in your `.emacs`:

```
(defun window-width-to-font-size (window-width)
  ;; Insert a calculation to turn window width into 79 chars.
  )

(add-to-list
 'window-size-change-functions
 (lambda (frame)
   (dolist (window (window-list frame))
     (set-face-attribute
      'default nil
      :width (window-width-to-font-size (window-body-width window))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at library [`face-remap+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/face-remap%2b.el), which essentially does the opposite: When you shrink the text size the window size shrinks accordingly, so there is no wasted extra space surrounding the text. Dunno whether that code will help, but it might give you some ideas.